How to display my cover and my pages with turn.js
I hope you are doing well.
I am working on a leaflet with turn.js.
I can't seem to set the options correctly to get the result I want.
The flyer must be in "double" mode and the cover and end pages must be 300px wide.
The inside pages must be half and face each other
I tried to use the "when" option and add a condition.
The brochure starts in "single" mode and when turning to get to the first 2 pages, the spindle switches to "double" mode but it does not give a smooth result.
Page 2 suddenly appears


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 300,  
        height: 250,
        elevation: 50,
        gradients: true,
        display: "single",
        duration: "2000",
        /*when: {
            turning: function(event, page, view) {
                if (page === 1) {
                    $(this).turn("display", "double");
                }
            },
            turned: function(event, page, view) {
                if (page !== 1) {
                    $(this).turn("display", "double");
                }
            }
        }
        */
    });
});
 
.banner-300x250 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}

.back-cover {
background-color: blue;
}

#flipbook {
    position: relative
}

.page-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
}

.page {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: gold;
}

.cover {
    background: url(https://images-armis-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/armis/AnimCatalog/img/cover.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/turn.js/3/turn.min.js"></script>
    <div class="banner-300x250">
        <div id="flipbook">
            <div class="cover">First Page</div>
            <div class="page">Page 1</div>
            <div class="page ">
                Page 2
                <div class="vert"></div>
                <div class="bleu"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="page">Page 3</div>
            <div class="page">Page 4</div>
            <div class="page">Page 5</div>
            <div class="page">Page 6</div>
            <div class="back-cover">End page</div>
        </div>
    </div>



